# Redis plus plus set is very delayed in loop

Tags: qt, redis, redis-cluster

I'm trying to set data to Redis Cluster in this code: (I'm using this https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus#redis-cluster)

```
QByteArray request = m_client.readAll();
qDebug() << "get data from" << bk[static_cast<int>(id) - 1];
QString mess = QTextCodec::codecForMib(106)->toUnicode(request);
//    messss.fromUtf8(request);
QStringList l_mess = mess.split("|");

QRegularExpression  key("\"key\": \"(.*?)\"");
QRegularExpressionMatch m_key;

qDebug() << "Count " << l_mess.count();
for (int i = 0; i < l_mess.count(); i++)
{
    m_key = key.match(l_mess[i]);
    cluster1->set(m_key.captured(1).toStdString(), l_mess[i].toStdString());
    cluster1->rpush("fonbet", "i"/*m_key.captured(1).toStdString()*/);
}
```

And when  l_mess.count() just over 100 or 200, delay time in "for" loop is over 20 seconds!!

I tried to set a static key-value, but the delay is the same. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending 200-400 commands, you are seeing 200-400 ms per command, most of that time is network latency, RTT (Round Trip Time).

To improve your performance, use a [pipeline](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus#pipeline) to reduce RTT.

Be sure to check the section on [Pipeline and Transaction of redis-plus-plus](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus#pipeline-and-transaction) when it comes to Cluster.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But if i use mset, it would be faster?

Comment: That's a good idea, you can build a mset and rpush command and send both at the end, but without pipeline, you are sending two commands separate over the network. You would have two RTT, with pipeline you have 1